# Problema al acceder proyecto angular

Tags: angular, angular8

```
Algunas cookies están haciendo mal uso del atributo recomendado  “SameSite“ 22
Se bloqueó la carga de un módulo de “http://127.0.0.1:8000/runtime.js” debido a un tipo MIME no permitido (“text/html”).
127.0.0.1:8000
Ha fallado la carga del módulo con origen "http://127.0.0.1:8000/runtime.js". 127.0.0.1:8000:15:1
Se bloqueó la carga de un módulo de “http://127.0.0.1:8000/styles.js” debido a un tipo MIME no permitido (“text/html”).
127.0.0.1:8000
Ha fallado la carga del módulo con origen "http://127.0.0.1:8000/styles.js". 127.0.0.1:8000:15:1
Se bloqueó la carga de un módulo de “http://127.0.0.1:8000/polyfills.js” debido a un tipo MIME no permitido (“text/html”).
127.0.0.1:8000
Ha fallado la carga del módulo con origen "http://127.0.0.1:8000/polyfills.js". 127.0.0.1:8000:15:1
Se bloqueó la carga de un módulo de “http://127.0.0.1:8000/vendor.js” debido a un tipo MIME no permitido (“text/html”).
127.0.0.1:8000
Ha fallado la carga del módulo con origen "http://127.0.0.1:8000/vendor.js". 127.0.0.1:8000:15:1
Se bloqueó la carga de un módulo de “http://127.0.0.1:8000/main.js” debido a un tipo MIME no permitido (“text/html”).
```

Comment: A veces este error sucede por el `<base>` no esta apuntando correctamente, verifica que tu `path` relativo sea correcto.

Comment: Añadiendo al comentario de @OscarLudick, por defecto, Angular configura (en el respectivo index.html) `<base href="/">`, ya que asume que la aplicación le levantará en la raíz del dominio.